# How do I run a specific test in Buck?

Tags: buck

I can run all tests in [buck](/questions/tagged/buck) using `buck test //...`

How do I run one specific test?

Comment: Those who interested in this can check [this](https://buckbuild.com/command/test.html) out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--test-selectors` method lets you pick a single test, but that doesn't have full support for all languages.